# What is the best way to find out from 2 columns of dates how many were 'how many weeks' late

Tags: excel, pivot

I have created an additional column telling me the number of weeks between them and then creating a Pivot table, is this the best way? I only know the basics of Pivot tables.  This is an example of the data I need in Grey

[image: 1]

Comment: How did you calculate weeks? If it is rounded you can use COUNTIF with -1 for 1 week late, -2 for 2 weeks late, >0 for ontime.

Comment: Hi   I used divide by 7, then had to insert another coloumn to do a rounddown.
Yes I have started to use countIF.
thank you